# Hello, how can I show 2 record in one column based on ID?

Tags: ajax, laravel, database, multiple-columns

[image]

Example, I want to show in column : 12144 = 6, 13

What should I do? Thanks, hope you're help me!

Answer (score 0):

you can change the `role_id` data type to TEXT or JSON and add a cast to it

`protected $cast=['role_id'=>'array'];`

see more
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting